# jython connection to csv file

Tags: python, csv, jython

Hi 
I have a code to read the csv file

```
import csv
d = csv.reader(open('C:/Documents and Settings/242481/My Documents/file.csv'))
for row in d:
    print row
```

This code returns all the rows in the csv file
Is there any way i can read one row at a time.
And each time i execute the print line i need to get the next row.
Thanks in advance
Aadith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should work the way you have it, but maybe the EOL characters are not what is expected for the system you're on. try opening it with 'rU': open('file.csv', 'rU')

to verify that it's printing one row at a time, you could print a blank line between rows:

```
for row in d:
 print row
 print
```

or pause it:

```
for row in d:
 print row
 raw_input('continue-> ')
```

For your other code, it should be something like:

```
def value():
 infile=open("C:/Documents and Settings/242481/My Documents/file.csv", "rU")
 data = [row for row in infile]
 infile.close()
 return data
```

Always close your open files. It's good practice, even though not always strictly necessary. And 'file' is a Python class name. Although you can use these any way you wish, doing so can lead to hard-to-find bugs later on.

Comment: Oki aftr openin the csv file with 'rU' how do i print the rows.?
what command should be executed to print one row at a time.?

Comment: the same way your code already has it. just add the rU to your open statement, and leave everything else the same

Comment: its still priinting the entire csv file.

Comment: no..its giving al the rows at the same time.. What i want is each time i execute the print row statement oly one row of the excel file should print.

Comment: hey i have this piece of code:
def value():
    file=open("C:/Documents and Settings/242481/My Documents/file.csv")
    for row in file:
        return row
but when i run it, it returns only the first row of the file.
i need it to return all the rows.....